# Get info about shared Google Plus post that is not in public access

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I have site from which users share posts to Google+ and use Google Plus API to get info about this activities, but if user select some circle at share step, G+ API return 404 error.
Is it some way to get info about this posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data.

[API documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/api/)

Comment: thanks, and no other google API can do this? Google plus domain API?

Comment: The Domains API is limited to Google Apps accounts aka non Gmail accounts.